# Delete strikethrough text

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I found code which removes strikethrough text in Tables in a PowerPoint file.

How could I modify the code to work on any shape type (e.g. text boxes etc.)?
Note: As some text is strikethrough and other text not, I do need this character by character approach.

```vb
Sub testIterateShapesType()
    Dim sl As Slide, sh As Shape, tbl As Table, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    For Each sl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each sh In sl.Shapes
            If sh.Type = msoTable Then
                Set tbl = sh.Table
                For i = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
                    For j = 1 To tbl.Columns.Count
                        For k = tbl.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Count To 1 Step -1
                            If tbl.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(k, 1).Font.Strikethrough Then
                                tbl.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(k, 1) = ""
                            End If
                        Next k
                    Next j
                Next i
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next adapted code and send some feedback:

```
Sub DeleteStrikeThroughChars()
     Dim sl As Slide, sh As Shape, tbl As table, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
     For Each sl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each sh In sl.Shapes
            If sh.HasTextFrame Then
                For k = sh.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Count To 1 Step -1
                    If sh.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(k, 1).Font.Strikethrough Then
                        sh.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(k, 1) = ""
                    End If
                Next k
            End If
            If sh.Type = msoTable Then
                Set tbl = sh.table
                For i = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
                    For j = 1 To tbl.Columns.Count
                        For k = tbl.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Count To 1 Step -1
                            If tbl.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(k, 1).Font.Strikethrough Then
                                tbl.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(k, 1) = ""
                            End If
                        Next k
                    Next j
                Next i
            End If
        Next
     Next
End Sub
```

If something is missed, please specify what type is the respective shape...

Comment: Hi @FaneDurue, thank you so much for tkaing the time to answer, it is really appreciated.. I tested your code and it works very well.. It is also a relatively simple modification from the initial code I published... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Basically, for all shapes that have text, the logic to remove some characters (eg all characters that are formatted with strike through) is the same.

There are 2 things that you need to check:

Some shapes doesn't have a text, so you have to skip them: Knowing if a shape has text is easy, just check the property `HasTextFrame`. If this is false just skip it.

Some shapes have childs that contain the text. I know at least three cases:

- Tables (that's what you code is already handling), you need to loop over all cells of all rows of that table.
- Groups of shapes. Groups can be handled by looping over all GroupItems (that is the collection of shapes within that group)
- Charts. Charts are very special and I will simply skip them.

What I did is to split the code you have into single routines.

- `processPresentation` loops over all slides of the active presentation
- `processSlide` loops over all shapes of a slide
- `processShape` handle the different shape types
- `processText` handles the text for one single shape

This makes it easier to understand the code (you don't have so many nested loops) and every routine serves just one purpose. It also makes it much easier to test: For example during testing, I made a presentation with one slide with several different shapes (and strike through text), copied that slide and then run the code only for the first slide. After testing, I simply copied the copy and had all my strike through text ready for the next test.

If you look closely, only the part in `processShape` is really new compared to your code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ProcessPresentation()
    Dim sl As Slide
    For Each sl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        processSlide sl
    Next sl
End Sub

Sub test()
    processSlide ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
End Sub

Sub processSlide(sl As Slide)
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In sl.Shapes
        processShape sh
    Next
End Sub

Sub processShape(sh As Shape)
    Dim child As Shape
    Select Case sh.Type
        Case msoGroup
            ' For groups: Process all shapes within group
            For Each child In sh.GroupItems
                processShape child
            Next
        Case msoChart
            ' Debug.Print "Chart"
        Case msoTable
            ' For tables: Process all cells
            Dim row As Long, col As Long
            For row = 1 To sh.Table.Rows.Count
                For col = 1 To sh.Table.Rows(row).Cells.Count
                    Dim cell As cell
                    Set cell = sh.Table.Rows(row).Cells(col)
                    processText cell.Shape
                Next
            Next
        Case Else
            ' Simple Shape
            processText sh
    End Select
End Sub

Sub processText(sh As Shape)
    If Not sh.HasTextFrame Then
        ' Debug.Print sh.Name; " has no text"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim k As Long
    For k = sh.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Count To 1 Step -1
        If sh.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(k, 1).Font.Strikethrough Then
            sh.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(k, 1) = ""
        End If
    Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @FunThomas thank you so much for tkaing the time to answer, it is really appreciated.. I tested your code and it works very well.. It is also great to have the explanation.. and your code is easy to follow... Thanks again